# How to handle button click while using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing alarm app.

I used broadcast receiver to receive alarm time.

When alarm times up, I show a activity which starts ringtone & vibrate using AsyncTask for 2 minutes.

In this activity I have two buttons named

1. Plus
2. Minus

When I press any of these buttons its click event is delaying to fire, means not getting clicked as I press button due to asyncTask running in backgroung(playing ringtone).

I read that asyncTask runs on seperate thread,

Than my button click event should fire as it pressed but in this case its not doing same.
If any body had this situation and got solution then please suggest me!
Below is my code.
called using :

```
new RingtonePlay ().execute("");
```

following is implementation.

```
public class RingtonePlay extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try 
        {
            audioManager    = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            originalVolume  = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            vibratorObj     = (Vibrator)mContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

            volume  = originalVolume;

            listObjs.clear();
            listObjs.add(audioManager);
            listObjs.add(originalVolume);
            listObjs.add(vibratorObj);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Cursor cursorSettings   = dbHelper.getAllRecords(Info.SETTINGS);
            if(cursorSettings!=null && cursorSettings.getCount()>0)
            {
                cursorSettings.moveToFirst();
                durationInMilliSeconds  = cursorSettings.getString(cursorSettings.getColumnIndex(Info.DEFAULT_DURATION));
                vibrate     = cursorSettings.getInt(cursorSettings.getColumnIndex(Info.DEFAULT_VIBRATE));

                if(toneName.equals(""))
                {   
                    toneName    = cursorSettings.getString(cursorSettings.getColumnIndex(Info.DEFAULT_TONE_NAME));
                    tonePath    = cursorSettings.getString(cursorSettings.getColumnIndex(Info.DEFAULT_TONE_PATH));
                }
                listObjs.add(vibrate); // For vibration [ YES = 1, NO = 0]
            }
            else
            {   
                listObjs.add(0); // For vibration [ YES = 1, NO = 0]
            }   
            if(cursorSettings!=null)
                cursorSettings.close();

            durationInMilliSeconds = 5000;

            ringTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, tonePathURI);

            if(ringTone!=null)
            {   
                ringTone.play();
            }

            if(ringTone==null && vibrate==0)
            {
                // No need to start any counter...
            }
            else
            {   
                timer = new MyCountDownTimer(durationInMilliSeconds, 1000, ringTone, mContext, listObjs);
                timer.start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, AsyncTask does run on a background thread and should not be blocking your UI thread if you're implemented it correctly. Show us your code, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

Of the 4 functions in `AsyncTask`, only `doInBackground()` is running in its own Thread off of the main UI Thread. Therefore, make sure that you are playing your ringtone from within `doInBackground()` and that you are starting the `AsyncTask` with its `execute()` function.

`AsyncTask.doInBackground()` will not stop your `Button` presses from firing unless you have called it directly instead of executing the `AsyncTask`.

Presumably, you have a short sound file which you are playing over and over for 2 minutes.
Each time the sound finishes playing, you should check for several things to decide if you should play again. A `while()` loop within `doInBackground()` will work well for this.

- If two minutes have elapsed, don't play the sound again.
- Your "Plus" and "Minus" `Button` presses can modify the two minute time.
- You can add a "Stop" button to zero out the time and stop the
  `AsyncTask` at the next cycle.